# Contact page php

Tags: php, html, contact-form, contactus

Problem - > on clicking send button opens 'send.php' code in the browser and no success message displaying

### Html code-

```
    <form action="send.php" name="form1" method="post" id="third1" style="margin-left:15%; margin-top:5%; 
    border:none">

    <!-- Name -->
    <label><strong><span class="blue">*</span> Name : </strong></label>
        <input id="name" type="text"size="20" />
        <br>
    <!-- Email -->
    <label><strong><span class="blue">*</span> Email : </strong></label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="20" />
        <br>

    <!-- Subject -->
    <label><strong><span class="blue">*</span> Subject : </strong></label>
        <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="20" />

    <!-- Message -->
    <label for="msg"><strong><span class="blue">*</span> Your message : </strong></label><br />
        <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" class="validate['required']" rows="10"
                    cols="30"></textarea>

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="buttonSubmit" value="Send it!" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
 <?php

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

 $to = "email@yahoo.com";
 mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);

 echo "Your message has been sent";
 ?>
```

Please help me finding out the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: where is `<form>` starting element and it's `action` and `method` attributes ?

Comment: Also, you are missing name attribute for name field.

Comment: which name attribute? I have put the form initial...

Comment: You have to name the input fields. "id" is for css and is not used when posting data.

Comment: He's talking about `<input id="name" type="text"size="20" />`.

Comment: `input id="name" name="name" type="text"size="20" />`

Comment: I have named the input fields...    <input id="email" **name="email"** type="text" size="20" />

Comment: why does it redirect to code for send.php ... I am getting no idea...

Comment: Lets begin with, do your have php installed? Because from what you told me is that the code is not even executed server side.

Comment: ya php is installed... m starting the wamp server and then running the code...

Answer (score 0):

@nevermind4 has spotted it right - you are missing name attribute on first input.

This does not have to be the real problem here though, can you please enable error reporting to see what is breaking your script?

Secondly mail returns true on success, false otherwise. Display of that message should be conditional, on false you should display a different one.

Answer (score 0):

If you see PHP code in the browser then PHP interpreter surely did not processed your code. Even if the PHP is not working / buggy the interpreter will never let the code appear on the client side. So that sounds like, your web server configuration is incomplete, or you see the form page out of the server's scope. Make sure the form html (but at least) the PHP file is in the server's document root directory or subdirectory or a properly configured vhost's path. Plus check your PHP running correctly by some simpler code, like